# PHP regex performed in a specific order

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of email addresses like so

```
smtp:nickp@office.email.com
smtp:nick@mailtrack.com
smtp:nick.p@email.com
SMTP:nick@email.com
smtp:nicholas@email.com
```

I need to do something which I think requires this to be done in a specific order.  Basically, I firstly need to check for smtp because although I dont show it above, there are some bad rows in the data.  I only need the emails that solely end in email.com.

Really, I think I need the line with the capital SMTP first.  The output I am looking for is this

```
nick: nick@relay.email.com
nick.p: nick@relay.email.com
nicholas: nick@relay.email.com
```

Maybe this will help you understand it better

```
$email_prefix_from_SMTP: email_prefix_from_SMTP@relay.email.com
$email_prefix_from_smtp: email_prefix_from_SMTP@relay.email.com
$email_prefix_from_smtp: email_prefix_from_SMTP@relay.email.com
```

So the emails will always be the same, and thats the prefix from the capital SMTP + relay.email.com.

The information before the colon will be the email prefix for the individual smtp.  What I have at the moment is this

```
if(preg_match_all('/smtp:(.*?@email\.com)$/im', $email, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        $emailPrefix = substr($match, 0, strpos($match, '@'));
        print_r($emailPrefix . ": " . $emailPrefix . "@relay.email.com" . "<br>");
    }             
}
```

That gives me the correct data before the colon, but the email addresses are not the same.

How can I output the data in the way I have described?

Thanks

Comment: There's an awful lot of _"I think X"_ in your question. What are you trying to do, and why do you think you need the SMTP (capitalized) lines to be processed first?

Comment: Mention the result you get and the result you expect to get.

Answer (score 0):

why do you search for the prefix later? you can split it directly in your parts:

```
$email = "smtp:nickp@office.email.com
smtp:nick@mailtrack.com
smtp:nick.p@email.com
SMTP: nick@email.com
smtp:nicholas@email.com";

preg_match_all("/^(.+):\s*(\S*)@(email\.com)$/igm", $email, $matches);
foreach($matches as $match)
{
    print_r($match[1] . ": " . $match[2] . "@relay.email.com" . "<br>");
}
```

please note that I haven't tested this code by now... the regex itself should work, but you get the idea of the rest.

Comment: doesn't even need regex,could just [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and split the string him self based on `:` and `@`